Book where the main character is shown a possible future prediction by a computer
The main character is shown a "possible prediction for his future by a computer based on input facts." In this "possible future," he sees that one of his classmates is just gone and no one can tell him what happened to her. After the simulated future is over I think I remember him trying to figure out why she is gone.

Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy SE! To increase your chances of getting a good answer, please [edit] your question and add more details, such as when you read/watched the work and what works you have already checked and ruled out. For more tips on how to improve your question, take a look at our guide on asking identification questions.

I'm  bit surprised to see the close votes. It didn't take much Googling to find the book from the information provided.

Possibly The Night Room by E. M. Goldman?


High school junior Ira is intrigued when he is chosen to participate in the Argus project-- a computer program that will simulate his tenth high school reunion. Six other classmates will participate, including Sandra, on whom Ira has a serious crush. But Tess, a reporter for the school paper, is worried about the dangers involved. And she's right. As the students enter the Night Room, one by one, they learn surprising things about themselves-- and discover that one of them isn't at the reunion. Argus predicts she'll be long dead...

I found it by Googling for computer predict future classmate science fiction site:goodreads.com/book/show/.
